# How to connect Apache Ignite Thin Client to Apache Ignite Cluster?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I have a running Ignite cluster and I use `AWS S3` for node discovery:

```java
TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder();
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials =
    new BasicAWSCredentials(igniteAccessKey, igniteSecretAccessKey);
ipFinder.setAwsCredentials(awsCredentials);
ipFinder.setBucketName(igniteBucketName);
ipFinder.setBucketEndpoint("s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com");

TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setClientMode(true);

cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
Ignition.start(cfg);
```

It works very well and I can connect to this cluster using `Apache Ignite Client` nodes.

But what about `Apache Ignite Thin Client`? `Thin client` uses `ClientConfiguration` class (instead of `IgniteConfiguration`) that requires a list of IP addresses of cluster nodes. AFAIK one can only hardcode that list of IP addresses.
 From official documentation:

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");
try (IgniteClient client = Ignition.startClient(cfg)) {
    ClientCache<Integer, String> cache = client.cache("myCache");
    // Get data from the cache
}
```

So I have questions:

1. How should I handle situations when a list of IP addresses change?
2. Is there any way to use **node discovery** for `Thin clients`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use domain names as well as IP addresses. But you can't use node discovery with thin clients.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what do people do in production? What is considered to be a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I you need node discovery, you must use thick client, that uses same configuration as server nodes (for discovery), just set client mode to true so this node does not serve caches.

You get more capability as local caching, better discovery options, notifications, but it seems it is counted as server node for licensing purposes.